# Section headings are going under fixed menubar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I never work with css, but this time I need to do. I got a strange behaviour. 
When I click on the menu from the header. Titles of the sections are going behind menu.

Here is my code :
http://jsfiddle.net/cu0520mL/

and here is my javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        scrollEvent();
        $(".menu >ul >li").click(function(){
            $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 60);
        });
        $('.more-blogs > ul').find('li').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('show-blog-lists');
        });
    });

function scrollEvent(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
             $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
         }else {
             $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you try it out and modify according to your requirement http://jsfiddle.net/sbuppkth/

```
.menu.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```